# Analysis where dependent variables are proportions

Tags: logistic, correlation, multiple-regression, proportion, demography

I have a set of demographic data (age, race, social class, etc.) for selected geographic areas. These independent variables are each proportional in each type, i.e. Area A: White 70%, Black 20%, Asian 5%, Other 5%... so each type sums to 1.

I have a series of dependent variables for which I wish to test the strength of correlation with these datasets. I am slightly inexperienced with statistical testing, but I am right in assuming I cannot use 'standard' tests (i.e. the ones I learnt in Stats 1!) with proportional independent variables as they are bounded? Initial research has led me to logistic regression (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/proportion.htm), but clearly this is for the dependant, not independent side - is this on the right track?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to understand, what variables are related to the various racial compositions? Do you have the N's for each area? Do you have full crosstabs (ie, %high SES teenage black, etc)?

Comment: Do you also have the totals? Because you will need this for your statistical tests..

Comment: @gung Each person was asked which of a series of options they prefer - I apologise for the deliberate vagueness, assume soft drinks or similar. I hold full overall preference data for these options (sampled from across the ~700 individual geographic units), but only ~100 of around ~700 of these smaller geographic units have been polled individually. I have netted these with the national result. (i.e. Area A prefers Option 1 (+)2 points over the national result at that time)

Comment: I wish to correlate the demographic data of these units with the netted preferred options to see if there is some significance - ultimately with the aim to predict where the strength of opinion against the national average in unpolled, geographic units may lie.

Comment: I do have the totals for each area, so I guess these aren't necessarily proportional, but assumed it would help for comparison purposes. I do not have crosstabs (using amalgamated data sources, some from census, some from elsewhere)

Comment: But you have data on each person in the survey, right? A person was called, they gave their demographic info & they said what soft drink they preferred, is that correct? & you are hoping to use this info to extrapolate to states / provinces where you didn't poll, so you can say what their preferences would be too. Is that what's going on here?

Comment: @gung We only hold specific demographic data for each respondent in some cases. In others, we simply hold a poll result for the area. Further, we only hold demographic data of certain kinds. So, instead of using poll sub-breaks, I'd like to use the overall demographic data I glean from the census, correlate this with the response variable and extrapolate this to other provinces.   
When I've been playing around with this initially I seem to get results of some statistical significance - I'm just concerned that the type of tests I'm doing are not completely suited to the data.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to really provide an answer to this question. I appreciate that you need to keep the details confidential, but you'll need to say a lot more about your situation, your data & your goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in the magnitude of dependence between two random variables, then you could calculate the spearman's rank correlation coefficient. For example, a spearman correlation of 1 implies that each of the variables is a perfect monotone function of the other. It does not matter whether the random variables are dependent or independent in your case.

A side note:

I would like to remind you that if your dependent variables are a mixture of continuous and discrete measurements, be careful when you make distributional assumptions on your dependent variables.